# How to adjust scroll up/down length in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal

I have Windows Terminal 1.10.2383.0 installed on a Windows 10. I frequently use scroll up/down (ctrl-shift-up and ctrl-shift-down) and it steps in 3 lines. I'd like to adjust this size but could not find any setting. Is there a way to change this stepping size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

You can change it directly from Windows Settings.

1. Open Settings -> Devices -> Mouse
2. Slide the "Choose how many lines to scroll each time" to the number of lines you want.
3. Restart Windows Terminal (if it was opened) for the changes to take effect.

[image: Mouse settings]

**Method 2**

In case you want finer control, modify Windows Terminal settings. Add the following in the settings.json file:

```json
        { "command": {"action": "scrollUp", "rowsToScroll": 20}, "keys": "ctrl+shift+up" },
        { "command": {"action": "scrollDown", "rowsToScroll":20}, "keys": "ctrl+shift+down" },
```

[image: Windows Terminal settings file]

Change 20 to the number of your liking. Save the file. The changes will immediately take effect.

Comment: Does this affect the behavior of arrow keys?

Comment: @Peregrino69 On Windows Terminal, Pressing Up or Down will show the history (at least on powershell) and pressing Ctrl+Shift+Up (or Down) will scroll by the numbers of lines set.

Comment: Hey  I just learned something new :-D So the mouse scroll affects also the arrow keys?

Comment: @Peregrino69 For Windows Terminal, yes as "rowsToScroll" follows by default  the mouse settings. Not sure about other apps.

Comment: Every window is affected by this setting now (even browser window), not just Window Terminal . Is there Windows Terminal specific setting for this?

Comment: Thx @ReddyLutonadio :-)

Comment: @Tekins See Edit (Method 2).